# Button on click not executing in Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, button

I am creating a side bar for data entry in google sheets. Everything in the scripts seems to have been working until I got to the on click execution potion. When I click on the button, nothing happens and there are no error messages. Below are the HTML and gs scripts. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

```
**InterDistForm.html Script:**

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <style>
    table {
      border-spacing: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 14pt;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      border-color: darkblue;
      background-color: lightblue;
      align: center;
    }
    td {
      border-color: white;
    }
    tr:hover {background-color: #D6EEEE;}

    input,
      select {
        font-size: 12pt;
        width: 100%;
      }
  </style>
  <body>

    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">School Year:</td>
          <td align="left"><input type="text" name="schoolYear" value = "2025" disabled/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td align="left">Date Received:</td>
          <td align="left"><input type="date" name="dateReceived" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th colspan="2"; style="background-color:Cyan;" >Student Information</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td align="left">Student ID:</td>
          <td align="left"><input type="text" name="studentID" value="0"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
      <br>
      <button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button> 
      
    </div>
    
  <script>

    function afterButtonClicked(){
      var schoolYear = document.getElementById("schoolYear");
      var dateReceived = document.getElementById("dateReceived");
      var studentID = document.getElementById("studentID");

      var rowData = {schoolYear: schoolYear.value
                      ,dateReceived: dateReceived.value
                      ,studentID: studentID.value
                    };
      
      google.script.run.addInterToForm(rowData);
    }

    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click",afterButtonClicked);

   </script> 
    
  </body>
</html>
```

```
**InterDistScript.gs Script:**

var ssTransfers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Transfers");

function loadForm() {
  
  const htmlForDialog = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("InterDistForm");
  const htmlOutput = htmlForDialog.evaluate();

  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showSidebar(htmlOutput);

}

function addInterToForm(rowData){

  ssTransfers.insertRowAfter(2); //Inserts blank row for data to be placed into
  ssTransfers.getRange(3,3,1,3).setValues([[
                               rowData.schoolYear
                              ,rowData.dateReceived
                              ,rowData.studentID
                            ]]); //needs double []

}
```

When I hard coded the values in the scripts, the scripts executed properly.

Answer (score 0):

I added a form and passed the data from the html to the server.  I presume that you can handle it from here.

gs:

```
function addInterToForm(obj){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

}
```

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <form id="f1">
    <table>
      <tr><td>School Year:</td><td><input type="text" name="schoolYear" value = "2025" disabled/></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Date Received:</td><td><input type="date" name="dateReceived" /></td></tr>
      <tr><th colspan="2" style="background-color:Cyan;">Student Information</th></tr>
      <tr><td>Student ID:</td><td><input type="text" name="studentID" value="0"></td></tr>
    </table><br>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="afterButtonClicked(this.parentNode)">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script>
    function afterButtonClicked(obj){
      google.script.run.addInterToForm(obj);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This one works okay as well:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <form id="f1">
    <table>
      <tr><td>School Year:</td><td><input type="text" name="schoolYear" value = "2025" disabled/></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Date Received:</td><td><input type="date" name="dateReceived" /></td></tr>
      <tr><th colspan="2" style="background-color:Cyan;">Student Information</th></tr>
      <tr><td>Student ID:</td><td><input type="text" name="studentID" value="0"></td></tr>
    </table><br>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="btn1">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script>
    window.onload = () => {
      document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click",function() {
        google.script.run.myfunk02(this.parentNode)
      })
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

- [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

The Dialog;

[image]

Comment: I would have put the addEventlistener in a window.onload.  But old school seems a lot easier to me.

Comment: I appreciate your help and the link to the validator. But the script is still not triggering the gs script to run. When I click the button, nothing happens. But when I run the gs script from the editor it does the first part of inserting a row but then errors out:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'schoolYear')

When I click the button, it doesn't even do the first step of inserting a row.

Comment: It's running the google.script.run and getting to the server now.  In  the future you might want to consider the use of a form.